# Nautilus .desktop launchers not working (19.04 disco)

Tags: nautilus, .desktop, 19.04

I recently updated my system to Ubuntu 19.04.

For some reason `.desktop` launchers seem to no longer work in Nautilus. They are now recognized as text files instead of being rendered as actual shortcuts:

[image: Screenshot - Nautilus]

this happens in Nautilus only. In comparison, this is how the same shortcut looks inside Nemo right now

[image: Screenshot - Nemo]

(I've tried the same with Caja and Thunar, everything working there)

Is this another design decision of the GNOME people, or is it just simply something that broke during the release upgrade?

**Important note** (maybe): I'm on Unity 7

Comment: Right click and select properties, then permissions and choose "allow to executing file as a program".

Comment: The file is marked as executable. As mentioned it's working in other file managers

Comment: I think i understand. Removing desktop icons with nautilus 3.26 probably left no need to keep the code for desktop shortcuts in. In my opinion that's not the best thinking. What if i created desktop launchers in different folders than my desktop? (which i did). Anyways, this probably explains it. If someone finds a workarround, feel free to post it here!

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this issue:

Create a bash script (e.g. /opt/bin/launcher.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

SELF=$(basename $0)

function usage() {
  echo "Usage: $SELF: desktop-file"
  exit 0
}

[ $# -lt 1 ] && usage

NAME=$1
[ "${NAME##*.}" != "desktop" ] && usage

EXE=$(cat $NAME | grep -i 'exec' | sed 's/exec=\(.*\)/\1/i')
[ -z "$EXE" ] && usage

echo -e "\n" | nohup $EXE > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Put this shebang in the first line of all of your .desktop files:

```
#!/opt/bin/launcher.sh
```

Hope it helps.